# Remix not allowing public arrays

Tags: contract-development, remix

I've seen sample code in various places that have public arrays, but when I try to create this contract in [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;
contract Ballot {
  uint8[] public proposals;
}
```

It always fails with

```
undefined errored: VM error: invalid opcode.
invalid opcode  The constructor should be payable if you send value.
    The execution might have thrown.
    Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

Again, this is during the creation of the contract. I've tried sending value (and adding a payable constructor); the error changes (`VM error: revert.`), but still does not succeed. I've also tried debugging; it steps through the constructor (if present), and then steps through the state field and fails there.

Comment: The code you posted compiles and works with Remix and solc compiler version 0.4.19. It's not clear how exactly to replicate the error (not obvious). You can generally ignore the "payable" aspect of the constructor failure message. It's a boilerplate hint. The message just means the constructor (not shown) failed.

Comment: @RobHitchens I was able to compile but I get the error when clicking the Create button on the Run tab. There is no constructor.

Comment: It does give the error but if you check to the right under the create button you'll see that your contract was created.

Comment: @CNuts: True. And it also gives that same error when I call some functions, but they also appear to be working. Please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: TBH I'm not feeling it yet with the new Remix and I lost sight of how most people are probably not using https://yann300.github.io/remix04. Your contract is fine. I see the error now. No, it doesn't add up for me.

Comment: @RobHitchens: I'm a newbie, and the [docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io) only refer to the official Remix and not the yann300 version. But thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does give the error but if you check to the right under the create button you'll see that your contract was created.

[image]

Comment: Also, the same error is spit out when functions on the contract are called. The error is displayed after the successful function result. My mind just saw the error as the last message, assumed it failed, and didn't scroll up to see those functions were actually succeeding.

Answer (score 0):

You get "VM Exception: invalid opcode" error in solidity, when I you had set a value in the "value input" before creating the contract.
So, to resolve such error you can set "value input" to  0 and retry to create the contract. It will work fine.

Comment: Setting the value to something else than 0 will cause an error without creating the contract. Having 0 as value will still generate the same error but will create the contract.